# How to round to 4 decimal places?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I have the following code and I wanted to round by 4 decimal places in Python 3. I tried using round but kept getting a syntax error.

```
fname = input("Enter a file name: ")
try:
    ffile = open(fname)
    ssum = 0
    nline = 0
    for nline, line in enumerate(ffile):
        if line.strip().startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
            colon = line.find(":")
            slash = line.find("\\")
            current_av = line[colon+1:slash]
            ssum = ssum + float(current_av)
            print ("Average Spam confidence: ", ssum/nline)
except:
  print "This file was not found"
```

I tried `ssum = (round(ssum, 4))`, but the decimals are not rounded.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post **the line it occurred** on and the **complete exception/error details**. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help. You show code does not use `round()` _anywhere_ so there is no way for us to replicate your error. See [mcve]

Comment: After ssum = ssum + float(current_av) I put ssum = (round(ssum, 4)) and the answer did not print to 4 decimal places.

Comment: You're printing `ssum/nline`, not `ssum`. Rounding `ssum` to 4 decimal places isn't going to magically also round `ssum/nline` to 4 decimal places. BTW, you report two different errors in your question: first you say you get a "syntax error", then you say "the decimals are not rounded". Which is it? Please show the _actual_ code you're running, and the actual complete error (verbatim, copied and pasted, not paraphrased) that you're getting. We might then have some chance of being able to help you. As it is, we're just guessing what you're actually doing.

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments. PS Find some code that you show works then add minimal code that doesn't work. Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

> I tried ssum = (round(ssum, 4)), but the decimals are not rounded.

Yes, that is the correct way to round. You have an extra set of parentheses on the outside, but that's not impacting the call. What you're doing is just like this example:

```
>>> import math
>>> round(math.pi, 4)
3.1416
```

> kept getting a syntax error.
>
> ```
> print "This file was not found"
> ```

That won't work, not in python3. Use parentheses when calling the print function:

```
    print("This file was not found")
```